# Why ping app is used in examples of routing protocols?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

Why ping app is specifically used to send data between nodes in the examples of routing protocols such as AODV & GPRS instead of a UDP app or TCP app in INET framework?
Is there a certain reason for using it to test any routing protocol?

Answer (score 2):

Because in real network ping is commonly used to test access to an element in the network. Ping uses ICMP and every instance of IPv4 or IPV6 entity in a device (e.g. router, host, server) handles ICPM requests. Therefore, there is no need to adding any application to use ping.